# Convert UTF-8 Unix LF .dat file to UTF-8 encoded CR LF .dat file using Perl

Tags: perl

I have an input .dat file with Unix LF encoding, I want my output file to be Windows CR LF with UTF-8 encoding using Perl. Currently this is how my code looks. How can I add CR to the existing LF in the file?

```
sub encodeUTF8 {
    my $ProcVars = $_[0];
    my $src = $_[1];
    my $des = $_[2];
    # open source file for reading
    open(SRC,'<',$src) or die $!;
    # open destination file for writing
    open(DES,'>',$des) or die $!;
    binmode DES;
    print("copying content from $src to $des\n");
    while (<SRC>) {
        s/^\N{BOM}// if $. == 1;
        print DES;
    }
    close(SRC);
    close(DES);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify the `:crlf` layer in [binmode](http://p3rl.org/binmode)

```
binmode DES, ':crlf';
```

[print](http://p3rl.org/print) can't take only the handle, it also needs to know what to print:

```
 print DES $_;
```

Comment: this is how i have a function

Comment: Please, update the question instead of posting the code into a comment.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: It is adding CR LF to the existing LF. I want LF to be replaced with CR LF

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I was reading incorrect file.